# Vista Starter installed, now trying to install Ubuntu... but how?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

my sister just bought a new netbook with Vista 7 Starter preinstalled... which very much sucks ;-)...

So, I wanted to install Ubuntu Netbook Remix as well... I read a manual which basically says that I have to shrink one of the Win7 partitions... the Ubuntu Installer should then use this "free" space as his partition... which he doesn't... he just shows me to use ALL of the hdd or partition it by myself... but it should actually use the free space automatically... HELP!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to shrink the Windows partition in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management. Right-click on your C: partition and choose Shrink Volume.

After you've shrunk your Windows partition, the free space should show up in the Ubuntu installer.

However, to see it, you'll need to choose the "partition it yourself" option, then select the unused free space when it shows you your current disk layout & asks where you want to install Ubuntu. Then you can let the installer automatically create the needed Linux partitions in the free space.

Answer (score 0):

once shrink the win7 c:/ then you can install using manual partition table and in ubuntu 9X you can even your my documents/my picture/my music from win7.

Answer (score 0):

Might I reccomend that you do something a little different to make the computer easier to use for your sister.  Buy a 8GB USB stick (SD Card is even better if your laptop can have one) and install ubuntu on that drive as the primary boot partition.  This will mean that whenever the USB/SD Card is inserted the Netbook will boot ubuntu, but vista will still be the same when it is removed.